# xsd validation fails during maven compilation

Tags: xml, validation, maven, xsd

I have an xsd which has an element having attribute :

```
<xs:attribute name="sdk_version" use="required" >
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="(([0-9]{1,4}.[0-9]{1,4}))"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

However my xml is like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <service_description
    xmlns="http://archiveschemas.aus.x.com/aus"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://archiveschemas.aus.x.com/aus 
                        aus.xsd"
    name="${serviceName}" 
    version="${serviceVersion}"
    **sdk_version="${CE-SDK-Version}"** 
    sdk_build="${CE-SDK-Release}">
    <component type="properties" filename="properties.xml" />
    <component type="servlet" filename="testlog-ear-${project.version}.ear" />
 </service_description>
```

However compilation fails with error:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:xml-maven-plugin:1.0:validate (default) 
>        on project testlog: While parsing 
>        C:\Assignment\testlog\testlog-svar\src\main\resources\manifest.xml, at
>        file:/C:/Assignment/testlog/testlog-svar/src/main/resources/manifest.xml, 
>        line 6,  column 67: cvc-pattern-valid: Value '${CE-SDK-Version}' 
>        is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '(([0-9]{1,4}.[0-9]{1,4}))' 
>        for type '#AnonType_sdk_versionservice_description'. -> [Help 1]
>        [ERROR]

My pom.xml looks like:

Comment: the error seems to be due to incorrect order of execution goals.

Comment: And the question is ... ?  Which part of "the string `'${CE-SDK-Version}'` does not match the regex `'(([0-9]{1,4}.[0-9]{1,4}))'` is unclear?